# How to get the rank of a perturbed adjacency matrix by adding x edges into the graph

Tags: graph-theory, matrix-rank, perturbation-theory

Given an undirected graph $G$ which has $n$ nodes and $m$ edges, and its adjacency matrix is $A$, which is a $n \times n$ $0$-$1$ matrix, $r(A)$ is the rank of $A$, when I add randomly $x$ edges into the graph $G$, we can get a perturbed matrix $\widetilde A$:

$\widetilde A = A + E$

where $E$ is the perturb  matrix which is also a $0$-$1$ matrix and it has $2x$ "$1$" entries. The location of these "$1$" entries is not fixed. Note that $\widetilde A$ is still a symmetric matrix.

The question is how can I get the rank of $\widetilde A$, that is, $r(\widetilde A)$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.